# Cypher - finding most common user + storing it

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Cypher in the StackOverflow database. I'm trying to find the user with the most upvotes, and then search the database for the number of posts that user made. I understand how to get the user with the most upvotes

MATCH (u:User)
ORDER BY u.upvotes DESC
RETURN 1;

But I don't know how to get that value and use it to find the number of posts that user made (connected to Post nodes).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your query is actually incorrect correct. It should have been:

   MATCH (u:User)
   RETURN u
   ORDER BY u.upvotes DESC
   LIMIT 1
2. I assume that you are following the example in [this log post](https://neo4j.com/blog/import-10m-stack-overflow-questions/). To also *efficiently* get the number of outgoing `POSTED` relationships made by the user with the most upvotes:

   ```
   MATCH (u:User)
   WITH u
   ORDER BY u.upvotes DESC
   LIMIT 1
   RETURN u, SIZE((u)-[:POSTED]->()) AS nPosts
   ```